# Take a url variable with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following url

```
http://www.test.info/link/?url=http://www.site2.com
```

How do I get the value of the url parameter with regular expressions in javascript?

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
function extractUrlValue(key, url)
{
    if (typeof(url) === 'undefined')
        url = window.location.href;
    var match = url.match('[?&]' + key + '=([^&]+)');
    return match ? match[1] : null;
}
```

If you're trying to match 'url' from a page the visitor is currently on you would use the method like this:

```
var value = extractUrlValue('url');
```

Otherwise you can pass a custom url, e.g.

```
var value = extractUrlValue('url', 'http://www.test.info/link/?url=http://www.site2.com
```

Answer (score 14):

Check out http://rubular.com to test regex:

```
url.match(/url=([^&]+)/)[1]
```

Comment: As in the RFC: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.3
The semicolon(';') character can also be used to delimit parameters, So I think the regex pattern would be like
`url.match(/url=([^&;]+)/)[1]`

Comment: This will also match something like [example.com/notthisurl=match&url=wontmatch](http://google.com) being it an unexpected behavior. To fix this I can imagine a regex like this one `url.match(/(\?|&)url=([^&]+)/)[2]`

Answer (score 3):

Might want to check this: http://snipplr.com/view/799/get-url-variables/ (works without regEx)

This one does use regEx: http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html

```
function gup( name )
{
      name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
      var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
      var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
      var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
      if( results == null )
        return "";
      else
        return results[1];
}


var param = gup( 'var' );
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, firstly, is that the whole query string? If so, all you need to do is split on the =:

```
url.split('=')[1];
```

Otherwise, you might want to use Jordan's Regex.

Answer (score 0):

On the answer code:

```
function extractUrlValue(key, url)
{
    if (typeof(url) === 'undefined')
        url = window.location.href;
    var match = url.match('[?&]' + key + '=([^&#]+)');
    return match ? match[1] : null;
}
```

If `key` is a last parameter in URL and after that there is an anchor - it enter code herewill return `value#anchor` as a value. `#` in regexp `'[?&]' + key + '=([^&#]+)'` will prevent that.